# magento 1 checkout page gives error "checkout is not defined" in console prototype.js::5598

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, onepage-checkout, prototype-js

i am using firecheckout for magento 1 checkout page gives error "checkout is not defined" in console prototype.js::5598.
because of that error sometimes customers can not place order.
can anyone help me. it gives error like below screenshot.
i am looking for a solution but can't find anywhere

[image]